# White notes on black background

Tags: piano, notation

I'm learning how to read notes, and i've encountered something that i don't quite understand. Could any of you can tell me why in this piece, some of notes are written white on black background?

- link to exactly moment of sonata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other videos I've seen, white notes on a black background aren't played in that portion of the video (first repeat when 2nd repeat is being played, etc.).